# Considering on selling/considering selling

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

When I google: ''I am considering on selling'' I get as a result: I am considering selling''. Do I have to omit ''on'' because it kind of sounds weird to me otherwise.

Why is it okay to say: ''I am planning on doing..'' and not okay to say ''considering on..'' or even ''I consider to sell''

Comment: When you look in an English dictionary to learn about the verb _consider_, do any of the example sentences contain the construction _"consider on"_? How about _"consider to"_? "Google" is not a very reliable tool for research. You will learn more by starting with an English dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

> When I google: ''I am considering on selling'' I get as a result: I am considering selling''. Do I have to omit ''on'' because it kind of sounds weird to me otherwise.
>
> Why is it okay to say: ''I am planning on doing..'' and not okay to say ''considering on..'' or even ''I consider to sell''

That is because each verb has naturally evolved differently, unfortunately. But fortunately, dictionaries tell us how each verb is used.

Dictionaries tell us that the verb '*[consider](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/consider?q=consider)*' can be *either transitive or intransitive*, but it's such a verb that doesn't need any preposition when used with an object. There's not much logic in it, but it's just the way it is. So, the idiomatic one is *"I am considering selling something."*

The verb '[plan](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/plan_2)' creates a verb phrase with '**on**' to mean that you *have a plan*, for example, *I plan on going camping.* This is saying you have a plan to go camping, and is different from the usage to mean that you *plan something*. When you want to mean you plan something you don't use 'on,' but you say "*I have to plan a strategy.*"

Comment: I see thanks, what about :''I consider to sell''

And are all of these correct:
''I plan on going'', ''I am planning on going'', ''I plan to go''

Comment: Consult a dictionary and see for yourself. :) Get used to looking at it. I've even liked them for you. The structure of "I am considering buying something" is a good thing to remember when taking an English exam. And whether 'plan doing something' or 'plan on doing something' is as I said above it's up to what you want to say.

Comment: typo: liked them for you -> linked them for you

Comment: To whom have voted down on this; please explain to me what is wrong with this.